# What are the performance implications of including Ruby IRB shell gems in production? (i.e. Pry / Byebug / awesome_print ...)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shell, heroku, irb, byebug

In Rails projects its common to see shell-enhancement gems only being included in the `development` / `test` sections of Gemfiles -- presumably because there is a performance or memory hit if these gems were included into the production Gemfile.

However, because I do quite a lot of work on my Rails production server on Heroku, I would like to pretty my shell up so that it could imitate development more (such as by including back in gems like `pry` and/or `byebug`, or `awesome_print`). However, I can't justify adding them into production if I know it could significantly slow down my app.

So what are the performance implications of including shell-enhancement gems like `byebug`, `pry` or `awesome_print` in Production on Rails?  Will they impact the performance of my single dyno production rails server even when I don't have a production server shell open?  Is it the memory hit that's a problem, or do these gems also impact the speed of my server even when I don't have a shell open?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really a performance impact. Those gems should not be called during the normal execution of your server. However, I would *strongly* suggest you set `pry` and any other such gems as `require: false` in your Gemfile, to avoid 1) the memory footprint of requiring them, and 2) the possibility that any stray `binding.pry`s left in some obscure code paths in your app will trigger a blocking `pry` session, pausing the thread and wasting resources on your server.

P.S. A quick Google search turned up a [post on the Bugsnag blog](http://blog.bugsnag.com/production-pry) detailing how they use `pry` in production.